# Playing sound effects without pausing delaying other methods (Java)

Tags: java, javasound

I'm writing a game that uses sound effects whenever the player shoots a missile, but right now the program waits for the sound effect to finish before continuing with further actions. I tried threading the audio and it works once, but the thread is now dead and there's no way to play the sound again. What is a way for me to play sound effects without "lagging" the game?

Comment: Got a small snippet that we could run to see similar behavior?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I cannot really help you, but you could separate the logic from the sound.  So that you have a own thread for the sound.

Maybe this tutorial can help you [Playing Sound in Java](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html)

Comment: The tutorial cited is called "Playing Sound in Java" and looks quite respectable and appropriate for the OP who by all indications is new to this particular tech.